# pandas - generating next closest year off of last digit

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When computing the expiration date of some financial instruments, usually all we have to go off of is the following:

```
Trade Date  RIC
5/22/1989   SPH0
5/23/1989   SPH0
5/24/1989   SPH0
5/25/1989   SPH0
5/26/1989   SPH0
```

Where the trade date is a day the instrument is being traded, and the RIC is a 4 letter string composed of:

```
First 2 characters = an asset class
3rd character = expiration month
last character = last digit of expiration year
```

Expiration months explained:

```
month_codes_to_int = {'F':'1', 'G':'2', 'H':'3', 'J':'4', 'K':'5', 'M':'6', 
             'N':'7', 'Q':'8', 'U':'9', 'V':'10', 'X':'11', 'Z':'12'}
```

I am generating an expiration year for every row by using the trade date and the RIC... I am doing so by iterating over the DF and filling an empty cell in a column every time with a function that will correctly compute the expiration date.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row['Trade Date'] = pd.to_datetime(row['Trade Date'])
    print(row['Trade Date'], row['RIC'])
    current_year = row['Trade Date'].year
    asset_class = row['RIC'].split[0:3]
    expiration_month = row['RIC'][2]
    expiration_year_last_digit = row['RIC'][3]
    expiration_year =
```

My methodology is to have the expiration date be the closest date with the month and year to the current date, so for 5/22/1989 for example it would be 3/15/1990 (day doesn't matter, 1990 is the closest year ending with a 0 to 1989).

Is there a way to automate this using pandas datetime features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create series containing your month, year, as well as the last digit of your `TradeDate` column.

```
m = df.RIC.str[2].map(month_codes_to_int)
y = df.RIC.str[3].astype(int)
s = df.TradeDate.dt.year.mod(10)
```

Then calculate your offset:

```
offset = np.where(y==s, 0, 10+y-s)
```

Finally, create your new column:

```
pd.to_datetime((df.TradeDate.dt.year + offset).astype(str) + m, format='%Y%m')
```

Output:

```
0   1990-03-01
1   1990-03-01
2   1990-03-01
3   1990-03-01
4   1990-03-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```